# Not able to detect the space for match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL formatted like this:

```
http://testsite1/mm/page1.php?tID=18&tSerial=TEST TT 1
```

And here is my JS:

```
var qs = location.search,
positionID = qs.match(/tID=(\w+)/)[1],
serialID = qs.match(/tSerial=(\w+)/)[1];
```

My problem is that when tSerial is having space e.g. `TEST TT 1` then my qs.match can not capture the space what changes must I perform here? What else must I change in order to capture the space too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allow spaces in the serial parameter like this:

```
serialID = qs.match(/tSerial=([\w\s]+)/)[1];
```